# Vue: Where to call API?

Tags: vue.js

I currently learning Vue and I am building a movie database app, where users can see movies fetched from an external API and sorted by popular and upcoming. 
I have to call different URLs for both categories and I was wondering if I should do that in each component or a separate, third component where all the fetched data is stored? 
Does it make sense to use Vuex for a small application like this or is there another best practice? Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

IMHO, Use of Vuex is not about size of application, but the structure. If you want a clean app structure, keep vue SFCs as *"simple"* as possible. Any logic should be in Vuex and any complex function should be in utility classes.

When you're dealing with an application (not individual components) that utilizes an API, I would recommend placing the API and data hydration into Vuex. (or rather a separate function, but initiated by vuex)

This would allow any component to have access to not only the data, but the loading status of the data. Allowing you (for example) to use something `v-if="dataIsLoaded"` for components that expect the data to be there, and `v-else` for loading indicators

Comment: Thank you, I did use Vuex in the end and it's actually not as complicated as it seems (especially compared to Redux).

Answer (score 2):

There are many resources online and here on stack overflow that will guide you in this. Without knowing how big your application is right now and how big is going to grow, it is difficult to suggest whether to use Vuex or not.  In any case, where you make your API calls is / should be independent of your state management.

In general API  calls in Vue applications can be made safely in the `created` lifecycle  hook of the component.

`created() {}`

If you are not going to reuse the data from the API in multiple components, then you can call it in the component where it is needed. If you want to want to do it in a third component, it has to be a kind of wrapper around around your components for popular and upcoming and then pass the data received as a prop to these components.

Approach 1:

- MoviesWrapperComponent: Makes the API calls and passes it down to other components
- PopularMoviesComponent: Receives data from MoviesWrapperComponent
- UpcomingMoviesComponent:  Receives data from MoviesWrapperComponent

Approach 2:

- PopularMoviesComponent: makes its own API calls.
- UpcomingMoviesComponent: Makes its own API calls.

Answer (score -3):

How I do it, is the Ajax calls in each method as in this way it's easier to handle the promisses and the scope of the components.

I'm using the popular Axios plugin, and i'm very happy with it. https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-axios

I wouldn't use vuex if you just need to share data between a couple of components, but you can use it if you want to learn how to work with vuex.

Comment: Again, the opener is not asking for packages that can be used to make API calls. But rather where and how to structure his application.